# Use argument's property as type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to assign type to property of class that depends on passed property in argument. I wonder if it's possible.

Example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    g,
    f,
    h,
}

interface MappedTypes {
    [MyEnum.f]: X
    [MyEnum.g]: Y
    [MyEnum.h]: Z
}

class MyClass {
    a: string // does not matter
    b: something like MappedTypes[c]
    c: MyEnum

    constructor(params: { a: string; b: MappedTypes[<inherit from c>]; c: MyType }) {
        // for example
        // if c === MyEnum.g
        // b must be Y as mapped in MappedTypes  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is make your class [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in `E`, the type of the `c` property, and give `b` a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) like `MappedTypes[E]`.  This is the closest I can get to the code you're writing now:

```
class MyClass<E extends MyEnum> {
    a: string
    b: MappedTypes[E]
    c: E
    constructor(params: { a: string; b: MappedTypes[E]; c: E }) {
        this.a = params.a;
        this.b = params.b;
        this.c = params.c
    }
}
```

Beware though that once you use a generic like this you might find it difficult inside the implementation of `MyClass` to use `b` and `c` in a correlated way.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for more information.

---

Another way to proceed here is to keep `b` and `c` bundled into a single `params` property of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) type, like this:

```
type Params = { [K in MyEnum]: { a: string, b: MappedTypes[K], c: K } }[MyEnum]
```

If you examine `Params` you'll see that it evaluates to the following union:

```
/* 
type Params = 
  { a: string; b: Y; c: MyEnum.g; } | 
  { a: string; b: X; c: MyEnum.f; } | 
  { a: string; b: Z; c: MyEnum.h; }
*/
```

And then you could define `MyClass` like this:

```
class MyClassU {
    constructor(public params: Params) { }
}
```

So instead of `this.b` you'd need to refer to `this.params.b`, which might be annoying. On the plus side, you will be able to do things like `switch` on `this.params.c` and the compiler will understand that it has an implication for the type of `this.params.b`:

```
    someMethod() {
        switch (this.params.c) {
            case (MyEnum.f): {
                this.params.b; // known to be X
            }
        }
    }
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gWAFBW1A5gGkxygDNCscALcgX00wEsQAXYAJxIEMBjYKADSgooADwBcUAM7M2TXFDoYmrDjz4BNIVDgTkAI3YLGLdl15QAWloBeEvQHt7AG2CcQRpSdXmYnAA5+wAAmACpwgZJCRDgA2vBIkAB0JAC6EvzR2HGIyIm4aVDqmVDZCRCJlAUWmIqY3E6ckpHwAMINTQA8CFDAIqwgQc05kAB8URTYnBLSsiDyxXoSvgHBYRExCCnF3BII2-YgM2DczPZsABR+nGycEJISwlNSMnIA3FCLsP6BoeHAkhsUu8dlBujQAJTjYjEZiUBiSRKcKAAXigVxud0Rr2KMLhCL0KLR11u+OxE2hsPhiW4hPRJOpxUUtQwzD+UAACsS7oThDEANJQJiwYYQAqPaYvOb4D5Lb6rP4AvkpaUggU0BSlZBbDCYAD0ACooJhWYEOVzIqjouLnrNcO9PupgUsRXl3uqAD5GijWmZvGUCJ3CsrJN1QT1WqBPX1ze0SCyB+K5ShuzD63X0DD1RpDNrZgCqUJw3AORxOZ0uYD0TgYNLpdwknIxkkhwmZxEk9ggwBgwFh9iC5xbOJwkgA7gxmNxKFBzpSEXWEdwh+ToUXGnxzomkiRwQ9h6vcVSF4k9O9dbqoABrED2UfuU4fPgZFcHxQHjzEZk0IA)